# How to handle Eject action from Nautilus in FUSE filesystem?

Tags: debian, nautilus, fuse

I've written a FUSE filesystem in Python and I am having trouble getting it to un-mount properly when I click on the eject button in the Files utility (this is being tested in Debian 8/Jessie).  When I try to eject the filesystem, I get a permission denied error.

Going over to the command-line, I can `sudo umount ~/mnt/point` or I can `fusermount -u ~/mnt/point` and both work correctly.  The following lines are printed to syslog every time I try and eject through the Files GUI:

```
gnome-session[1204]: (tracker-miner-fs:1377): Tracker-WARNING **: Unmount operation failed, adding back mount point...
gnome-session[1204]: (tracker-extract:1408): libmediaart-WARNING **: Unmount operation failed, adding back mount point...
gnome-session[1204]: (tracker-extract:1408): Tracker-WARNING **: Unmount operation failed, adding back mount point...
```

Looking through the fusepy code I'm importing for the FUSE support (the exact library I'm using is here: https://github.com/terencehonles/fusepy) I don't see any function callbacks I can hook into to get un-mount requests from the GUI (my understanding is that `fusermount` is supposed to handle that stuff behind-the-scenes anyway).

I even wrote a simple umount helper script at `/sbin/umount.<fstype>` to wrap `fusermount`, but that didn't change anything in the behavior or the logs.  I should also note that my program implementing my FUSE filesystem is running as the same user I am logged into Debian as.

What do I need to do in my FUSE filesystem to properly handle the eject action by a user in the Debian interface?